# Activity lifecycle: what to do when work is done in a child activity?

Tags: android

There are plenty of questions about activity lifecycle, but I couldn't find the suitable one.

I have an Activity (named A) which shows the cars from one user. Internally, the activity stores `userId` into a variable to load user's cars in the list. `userId` comes from previous activity.

When user presses the 'new car' button on A, Activity B is launched. User fills the car's form and presses save. User's new car is persisted to database.

**At this point, which method must be called to return to activity A from B?**

1. Should I call `finish()`? Then, user returns to A and B is destroyed. But, what happens if A was destroyed before? How can A be restored if `userId` is not present?
2. Maybe calling `startActivity(A)` with `userId` as intent extra? But then, I'm creating a new activity!
3. Other options?

I'm sure somebody would help to clarify these concepts. :)

Edit:

See comments of accepted answer for more information.

Comment: check out startActivityForResult() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: use startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) and in on activity use  `@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}` in A

Comment: Thanks to both of you. But I'm not expecting a result from B! Are you suggesting to return always userId for refreshing the list? Seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finish should be called to return.

1) if A was destroyed it will be recreated by android, unless you called finish() on it. If you saved its state properly there shouldn't be a problem at all.

2) This would just move Activity A back to the top of the Stack or creting a new Activity, depending on what flags you add to the intent.

3) I'd use startActivityForResult in Activity A to start B and then let the user enter the values, put set the result in B and call finish().

Comment: 1) with `onSaveInstanceState()`, right? 3) But the result in this case is always `userId`, I'm not really expecting a result. Anyway, it's a good solution. :)

Comment: 1) yes 3) Well then you can still use the call to OnActivityResult to invoke further steps, whatever they may look like.

Comment: I have been testing my app, with 'Immediately destroy activities' enabled on DevTools emulator's app. Here, some comment: 1) For variables stored in Activity class, like `userId`, it's not necessary to save its state with `onSaveInstanceState()`. These values are restored automatically. It's different for values from TextViews or similar, I think this is the main goal of `onSaveInstanceState()/onRestoreInstanceState()`. Hence, I have only to call ´finish()´ on B, and even if A was destroyed, the activity loads without problem displaying the refreshed information. Thanks for your help @Martze!